# Unable to access admin settings page wso2 api-m

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to access the admin settings from the admin page

```
https://localhost:9443/admin
```

But the settings drop down is empty. Is there any process I need to follow to enable this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the Alerts configuration which was under the `Settings` tab earlier has been moved to the analytics dashboard since 2.6[1]. That's why it's empty now. Ideally, the `Settings` tab should have been removed.

Anyway, you can ignore this.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Configuring+Alerts